# Optaplanner Chained-through time with variable start time

Tags: java, optaplanner, vehicle-routing

I'm currently working through a Vehicle Routing Problem.
The issue I'm seeing is that each stop also has a variable start and end time and also a variable driver for each given stop.

My current solution has been to skip defining this as a chain or list and instead just mark them both as regular Planning variables at the cost of performance, but I've hit a snag when in full assert mode:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: VariableListener corruption after completedAction
> ... for that shadow variable (TripAssignment.previousTripAssignment) ... for that shadow variable (TripAssignment.dropoffTime) ... shadow variable (TripAssignment.pickupTime)

My constraints require knowing the previous assignment.

My current Planning Entity is as follows:

```java
package org.acme.schooltimetabling.domain;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.acme.schooltimetabling.domain.listener.PreviousTripAssignmentUpdatingVariableListener;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.entity.PlanningEntity;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.lookup.PlanningId;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.solution.ProblemFactProperty;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.variable.PiggybackShadowVariable;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.variable.PlanningVariable;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.variable.ShadowVariable;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@PlanningEntity
public class TripAssignment {

    private Trip trip;

    private ZonedDateTime pickupTime;
    private ZonedDateTime dropoffTime;
    private ZonedDateTime startTime; // represents the time the driver will start the trip
    @JsonIgnore
    private TripAssignment previousTripAssignment;
    private Driver driver;

    public Trip getTrip() {
        return trip;
    }
    
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "drivers" })
    public Driver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "possibleStartTimes" })
    public ZonedDateTime getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }


    public TripAssignment() {
    }

    public TripAssignment(Trip trip) {
        this.trip = trip;
    }

    @ShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "startTime", variableListenerClass = PreviousTripAssignmentUpdatingVariableListener.class)
    @ShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "driver", variableListenerClass = PreviousTripAssignmentUpdatingVariableListener.class)
    @JsonIgnore
    public TripAssignment getPreviousTripAssignment() {
        return previousTripAssignment;
    }


    @PiggybackShadowVariable(shadowVariableName = "previousTripAssignment")
    public ZonedDateTime getPickupTime() {
        return pickupTime;
    }


    @PiggybackShadowVariable(shadowVariableName = "previousTripAssignment")
    public ZonedDateTime getDropoffTime() {
        return dropoffTime;
    }

}
```

I'm using piggyback here, but the listener is updating multiple variables and using the current working solutions list of trips.

My listener:

```java
package org.acme.schooltimetabling.domain.listener;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Comparator;

import org.acme.schooltimetabling.domain.Location;
import org.acme.schooltimetabling.domain.TripAssignment;
import org.acme.schooltimetabling.solver.VehicleDeliverySolution;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.variable.VariableListener;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.director.ScoreDirector;

public class PreviousTripAssignmentUpdatingVariableListener
        implements VariableListener<VehicleDeliverySolution, TripAssignment> {

    public PreviousTripAssignmentUpdatingVariableListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEntityAdded(ScoreDirector<VehicleDeliverySolution> scoreDirector, TripAssignment entity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEntityAdded(ScoreDirector<VehicleDeliverySolution> scoreDirector, TripAssignment entity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector<VehicleDeliverySolution> scoreDirector, TripAssignment entity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector<VehicleDeliverySolution> scoreDirector, TripAssignment entity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<VehicleDeliverySolution> scoreDirector, TripAssignment entity) {
    }

    private void setPreviousTripAssignment(ScoreDirector<VehicleDeliverySolution> scoreDirector,
            TripAssignment assignment,
            TripAssignment previousTripAssignment) {
        scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(assignment, "previousTripAssignment");
        assignment.setPreviousTripAssignment(previousTripAssignment);
        scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(assignment, "previousTripAssignment");
    }

    private void setPickupTime(ScoreDirector<VehicleDeliverySolution> scoreDirector, TripAssignment assignment,
            ZonedDateTime pickupTime) {
        scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(assignment, "pickupTime");
        assignment.setPickupTime(pickupTime);
        scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(assignment, "pickupTime");
    }

    private void setDropoffTime(ScoreDirector<VehicleDeliverySolution> scoreDirector, TripAssignment assignment,
            ZonedDateTime dropoffTime) {
        scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(assignment, "dropoffTime");
        assignment.setDropoffTime(dropoffTime);
        scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(assignment, "dropoffTime");
    }

    private ZonedDateTime calculatePickupTime(ScoreDirector<VehicleDeliverySolution> scoreDirector,
            TripAssignment previousAssignment,
            TripAssignment assignment) {
        Location previousLocation;
        if (previousAssignment != null) {
            // The driver has a previous assignment that he's coming from
            if (previousAssignment.getDropoffTime().until(assignment.getStartTime(), ChronoUnit.HOURS) > 4) {
                // The driver had a previous assignment, but he's had a long break inbetween.
                // TODO: Fix this up.
                previousLocation = assignment.getDriver().getHome();
            } else {
                previousLocation = previousAssignment.getTrip().getDropoffLocation();
            }
        } else {
            previousLocation = assignment.getDriver().getHome();
        }
        Duration travelTime = scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution().getBikingDropoffToPickupDuration()
                .get(previousLocation, assignment.getTrip().getPickupLocation());
        if (travelTime == null) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Incomplete distanceMatrix from "
                            + (assignment.getDriver().getHome() == previousLocation
                                    ? "(Driver " + assignment.getDriver().getId() + " Home)"
                                    : "(" + previousAssignment.getTrip().getId() + " Previous Assignment)")
                            + previousLocation + " to "
                            + assignment.getTrip().getPickupLocation());
        }
        // Calculate the end time based on the travel time and start time
        ZonedDateTime startTime = assignment.getStartTime();
        return startTime.plus(travelTime);
    }

    private ZonedDateTime calculateDropoffTime(ScoreDirector<VehicleDeliverySolution> scoreDirector,
            ZonedDateTime pickupTime,
            TripAssignment assignment) {
        Duration travelTime = scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution().getDrivingPickupToDropoffDuration()
                .get(assignment.getTrip().getPickupLocation(),
                        assignment.getTrip().getDropoffLocation());

        return pickupTime.plus(travelTime);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<VehicleDeliverySolution> scoreDirector,
            TripAssignment assignment) {
        if (assignment.getStartTime() == null) {
            System.out.println("No start time set, setting variables to null");
            setPreviousTripAssignment(scoreDirector, assignment, null);
            setDropoffTime(scoreDirector, assignment, null);
            setPickupTime(scoreDirector, assignment, null);
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Start time has been set, moving");
        TripAssignment previousAssignment = scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution().getAssignments().stream()
                .filter(aAssignment -> aAssignment.getDriver() == assignment.getDriver())
                .filter(aAssignment -> aAssignment.getStartTime() != null)
                .filter(aAssignment -> aAssignment.getStartTime().isBefore(assignment.getStartTime()))
                .max(Comparator.comparing(aAssignment -> aAssignment.getStartTime()))
                .orElse(null);
        System.out.println("Setting previous assignment to " + previousAssignment);
        setPreviousTripAssignment(scoreDirector, assignment, previousAssignment);
        ZonedDateTime pickupTime = calculatePickupTime(scoreDirector, previousAssignment, assignment);
        System.out.println("Setting pickup time to " + pickupTime);
        setPickupTime(scoreDirector, assignment, pickupTime);
        ZonedDateTime dropoffTime = calculateDropoffTime(scoreDirector, pickupTime, assignment);
        System.out.println("Setting dropoff time to " + dropoffTime);
        setDropoffTime(scoreDirector, assignment, dropoffTime);
    }
}
```